# How can I rearrange my complete bipartite graph so that it has a row of nodes on top and a row of nodes on bottom and center them?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code is below.  It creates $K_{3,5}$ like I want, but I want to flip it 90 degrees and center the nodes.  How can I?

EDIT: Figured out how to flip it.  I just replaced branch down with branch right and grow left with grow down, but still can't figure out how to center the nodes

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphs.standard
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
   \graph[nodes={draw, circle,fill=myblue}, radius=.5cm,
           empty nodes, branch down=2 cm,
           grow left sep=4cm] {subgraph I_nm [V={a, b, c, d, e}, W={1,...,3}];
  a -- { 1,2,3};
  b -- { 1,2,3};
  c -- { 1,2,3};
  d -- { 1,2,3};
  e -- { 1,2,3}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using node sets. You can choose the coordinates of the nodes ahead of time and then refer to them later in the graph. I'm not sure why the command `\graph { (w nodes) -- (v nodes) };` doesn't work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphs.standard
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}[new set=v nodes, new set=w nodes]
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4,5} \node [set=v nodes, circle, draw, fill=myblue](v\y) at (4,2*\y){};
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3} \node [set=w nodes, circle, draw, fill=myblue](w\y) at (0,2+2*\y){};
  \graph { (w1) -- (v nodes), (w2) -- (v nodes), (w3) -- (v nodes)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```